# View console of spawned native executable in azure remote login

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, native-code

I have a native exe, that is spawned by worker role of azure. When I remote login to cloud I dont find the console of exe. But process is running in background. How can I enable that.

```
var myProcess = new Process()
{
  StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Path.Combine(localstorage.RootPath, "NativeCode.exe"))
     {
         CreateNoWindow = true,
         UseShellExecute = true,
         WorkingDirectory = localstorage.RootPath,
         Arguments = args
     }
};
myProcess.Start();
```

When I tested in development fabric, I could see the console for above code.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar issue but not dig further why it happened in the Azure VM. However I was able to get the console windows out by launching the same application from a startup task.

What you really need is to launch the same application from a startup task however be sure to set the task property to run in background otherwise your role will lock up due to open console window. This way you get your console window and still have your worker role code intact with bare minimal change.

Comment: I tried the same as you said above. But no luck. With startup task I can not see the console in development fabric also. But it is running.(can see process in task manager) One more thing to mention, in this Azure app I have only worker role. Is that can be the reason for not showing the console (since worker role is a background process)?